# Is there a name for how some people pronounce their s slightly differently?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, speech, contemporary-english

I've noticed how some people pronounce the s sound in words using their upper teeth teeth and lower lip (instead of the conventional mostly internal way). This makes it sound almost *lispy*.

I don't really know how else to describe but some examples of celebrities that talk like this are **Eddie Murphy**, **David Spade**, and I think **Jim Parsons**.
Is there a word to describe this characteristic?

Comment: The verb in English for that is _lisping_. Many children do it for a while, but few adults.

Comment: Some adults pronounce **s** as **sh**. It's sometimes called an [affectation](https://www.lexico.com/definition/affectation).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp has a lot of detail

Comment: Upper teeth and lower lip?  Is that how I usually pronounce *F*?  I have heard *S* pronounced that way in some accents found in  British movies.

Comment: Oh it's not really a lisp but it does have a bit of a whistling sound to it. And yes it's like how you pronounce F, only you pronounce S instead.

Comment: Can you give us a youtube clip so I can see and hear it?

Comment: @aparente001 Here's a clip of [David Spade](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxCTOJGlUIPx2ftvk0d3CAwx0LFzD41SNG) and of [Eddie Murphy](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxFbYKVmBVVDyamY653ffzwn_RzwX5pAgX)

Comment: @Victor - Thanks for the links.  Eddie Murphy was playing a particular character -- he doesn't normally speak that way.  I agree he was speaking in a special way, but I thought I was hearing very little S sound -- not exactly a lisp.  I didn't know of David Spade before.  But I didn't hear a lisp from him.  Also I didn't see the teeth and the lower lip thing.

Comment: The only S in the Spade clip was when he said "So", it sounded like an "h" slipped in after the S. But that also could just have been a microphone artifact. @Victor

Comment: And Eddie Murphy seemed to be imitating a speech impediment, or at least a very strong accent that elides many consonants (notice how he says "opportunity"). It's even more pronounced in his Buckwheat character.

Comment: @Barmar I was in a rush to find those clips, so perhaps the ones I chose didn't quite capture it. I guess Eddie Murphy was doing a character in that clip. But what about this [clip](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxrVZ5ekwLhYBDxGiK7SM7Tu5uNaq0tvKj) of Eddie. I think it's more observable here. And also, Spade always talks like that. They both do.